# optimal isolation level for specific applications

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, transactionscope, isolation-level

Trying to understand isolation levels better - using entity framework and sql server

What would be the recommended isolation level for the following scenario -

An online booking system say for **flight tickets or event tickets**

Scenario -

Let us assume the capacity of the event is 100 - the pseudocode is as follows

```
   Begin transaction
   If SeatCount < 100 
   SeatCount  = SeatCount + 1
   End transaction
```

**EDIT** - in response to the comment here is how my pseudeocode would look like in actual code. I don't have the code and I am just looking to understand the scenario better. Let us say you have two tables "event" where you have two columns - "name, seatsbooked" and a table tickets where you have the individual ticket details.

```
         bool tSuccess = false;
        //this transactionscope resolves to serializable 
        using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope()            
        {                
            try{
            if(objectcontext.event.SeatsBooked < 100)
            {
                objectcontext.event.SeatsBooked = objectcontext.event.SeatsBooked + 1;
                ticket newTicket = new ticket{
                };
                objectcontext.tickets.AddObject(newTicket);
                objectcontext.SaveChanges();
            }
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
              //log and return 
           }
        }
        if (tSuccess)
        {
            bd.AcceptAllChanges();
        }
```

In this scenario  is it ok to assume  that read committed or repeatable read would result in overbooking or lost updates since two transactions can compete for the same seat.

**Is the recommended approach to go with serializable?**

Comment: its now even query, show us some real code, what you want to put into transaction

Comment: You can use a statement like `update SeatsBooked set SeatsBooked = case when SeatsBooked + @SeatsRequested <= TotalSeats then SeatsBooked + @SeatsRequested else SeatsBooked end where Name = @Name` to handle the test and update in one operation.  An `output` clause can provide the before and after values.  An appropriate isolation level is still needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeatable read is required, serializable is not necessary. Repeatable read ensures that the update will see the same seat count as the previous select did.

Your `TransactionScope` needs to span the entire logical unit of work, though. Not just the write.

In raw SQL it would be more elegant to use `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` but that is not available with EF.

In case of a conflict, a deadlock will easily occur. Either retry the entire logical transaction or select with `UPDLOCK`. `UPDLOCK` will avoid that deadlock entirely.

Comment: +1 I wrote some article about the way how this works: [Entity framework and pessimistic concurrency](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/09/entity-framework-and-pessimistic-concurrency/)

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - great article. That clears a lot of confusion. If you have written the article on table valued functions could you please share the link. Many thanks.